# WSSE with XML::Compile::SOAP::WSS and Perl

Tags: xml, perl, soap

So I'm having some problems adding a wsse header to my SOAP request.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Env qw( CYBS_ID CYBS_KEY );
use XML::Compile::Util qw( pack_type );
use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::SOAP::WSS;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;

my $soap = XML::Compile::SOAP11::Client->new;

my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new(
    'CyberSourceTransaction_1.62.wsdl'
);

$wsdl->importDefinitions('CyberSourceTransaction_1.62.xsd');

my $call = $wsdl->compileClient( operation => 'runTransaction');

my ( $answer, $trace ) = $call->(
    wsse_Security => {
        version => '1.1',
        schema => {
            Username => $CYBS_ID,
        }
    },
    merchantID            => $CYBS_ID,
    merchantReferenceCode => '42',
);

say $trace->printRequest;
```

Here's the output I get

```
mistake: tag `wsse_Security' not used at {urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.62}requestMessage
warning: Internal Server Error
Request:
  POST https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.02
  Content-Length: 381
  Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
  SOAPAction: "runTransaction"
  X-LWP-Version: 6.02
  X-XML-Compile-Cache-Version: 0.991
  X-XML-Compile-SOAP-Version: 2.24
  X-XML-Compile-Version: 1.22
  X-XML-LibXML-Version: 1.84
```

and the resulting xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><data:requestMessage xmlns:data="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.62"><data:merchantID>obfuscated</data:merchantID><data:merchantReferenceCode>42</data:merchantReferenceCode></data:requestMessage></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

the return?

```
1
```

earlier I had tried a `my $wss ...` code... but that didn't work either.

Here is the actual request I am trying to generate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">obfuscated</wsse:Password>

        <wsse:Username>obfuscated</wsse:Username>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>

  <soap:Body>
    <requestMessage xmlns="urn:schemas-cybersource-com:transaction-data-1.61">
      <merchantID>obfuscated</merchantID>

      <merchantReferenceCode>404</merchantReferenceCode>
    </requestMessage>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

perhaps someone has some idea as to how I'll get the wsse header added?

**update**

I can get this soap generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"/></SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

but everything I've tried putting in `wsse_Security` has resulted in an error like this:

```
mistake: tag `foo' not used at {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
```

*where `foo` equals whatever tags I try.*

Comment: That last update: the soap envelope tag isn't closed.

Comment: @Wivani oh yeah.. that's just from me trimming the body off... since it in theory shouldn't be relevant to what I'm trying to do in the header.

Comment: Just checking: the _request you want to generate_ .. have you tried using this in a client like SoapUI?

Comment: @wivani I had an actual working SOAP::Lite implementation, but SOAP::Lite doesn't have some of the goodies I want.

Comment: Good that you managed to get in touch with Mark. I'll remove my answer and comments to avoid clutter. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added examples to the distribution, to show how to do this. Also, I added a method which helps you generate this specific way of logging-in.  Released as [XML-Compile-WSS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile-WSS/lib/XML/Compile/WSS.pod) version [0.12](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile-WSS-0.12/lib/XML/Compile/WSS.pod).

```
my $call     = $wsdl->compileClient($operation);
my $security = $wss->wsseBasicAuth($username, $password);

my ($answer, $trace) = $call->
( wsse_Security => $security
, %payload
);
```

Comment: Note that the $wss object must either be constructed with `(..., schema => $wsdl)`, or `$wss->loadSchemas($wsdl)` must be called before the call to `wsseBasicAuth`.

Comment: In my case, I found the example in the following link to be most helpful: https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Compile::SOAP::WSS